# Equation of an 'n-Oval' (pins and loop of string method)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, curves

You can write the equations of an *n*-ellipse (polyellipse, egglipse, *k*-ellipse, etc...), where points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2)...,$ are foci:

$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_4)^2+(y-y_4)^2}...=d$$

For two points, the curve can be the same as an ellipse drawn with two pins and a loop of string (see fig. 1).

[image]

However, with more points, the curve seems to be the same as James Clerk Maxwell's construction method (see fig. 2)

[image]

You can also create various ovals by adding points to the loop and pins method shown in the first figure (see also fig. 3).

[image]

What I want to know is **how to construct equations for curves of the kind shown in fig. 3** given any number of points (akin to the above equation). I'd also be interested in knowing if there's anything **published on this type of curve.** Thanks.

Comment: Fig. 3 is just a sum of arcs of different ellipses, as far as I can judge.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I don't think that's quite right unless I'm missing something. If you add the ellipses you just get more standard ellipses. However the method in fig. 3. can produce something more akin to an n-ellipse / egg curve. It can also make other shapes with asymmetric pin configurations. You can draw fig. 3. with the pins as foci of multiple ellipses but I'm fairly certain the curve from that is very much an approximation with abrupt curvature change as opposed to the continuously changing curvature of drawing it with string.

Comment: A nice animation [here](https://www.robertdickau.com/oval.html) containing a reference to a book by Martin Gardner.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the link. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The figure below is a reproduction of your fig. 3: $ABCDEF$ are the pins and the string is held tight by the pencil at $P$.

As long as $P$ lies between the extensions of lines $FA$ and $BA$ we have that $PF+PB$ is constant. Hence $P$ describes an arc $HI$ of the ellipse with foci $F$ and $B$ (blue in the figure).

After $I$, point $P$ lies between the extensions of $FA$ and $CB$, with $PA+PB$ a constant. In this case $P$ describes an arc $IJ$ of the ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$ (orange in the figure). Note that the ellipses are tangent at $I$, because they share the same normal (the bisector of $\angle FIB=\angle AIB$).

After $J$, point $P$ lies between the extensions of $FA$ and $DC$, with $PA+PC$ a constant. In this case $P$ describes an arc of the ellipse with foci $A$ and $C$ (not shown in the figure), and so on.

In summary, the curve is a patch of 12 elliptical arcs, each arc being tangent with the preceding and following one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you have any idea of the curve's formula type?

Comment: There is no single "formula", it's the union of 12 elliptical arcs that could be written as a parametric piecewise equation, but it's very long and  clumsy.

Comment: I see that you'd need a piecewise to do it if you think of it as arcs of ellipses, but surely there must be some class of equations for the path traced by a loop of string stretched around a shape that is essentially a bunch of right triangles?

Maybe it could be done by modifying the involute equation.

Anyways thanks for the answers.

Comment: I agree with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

An idea.

I agree of course with the answer of Intelligenci Pauca, but I would like to say that there is some hope to have a single equation using absolute values like in the examples below (for different values of $p$) ; these curves are made of connected conical arcs (some of them may not be  elliptical arcs) ; moreover, in the points where the arcs are connected, there is no smoothness. But I am almost certain that it is possible, at least in certain cases, to assemble  second degree polynomials with or without absolute value(s) in order to get the curves you want.

[image]

$$3x^2+2y^2+|y+2x|+|xy|=p$$

SAGE program for the generation of the figure :

```
 var('x y');
 g=Graphics();
 for k in range(0,20) :
    p=k/8
    g+=implicit_plot(3*x^2+2*y^2+abs(y+2*x)+abs(x*y)==p,(x,-1,1),(y,-1,1))
 show(g)
```

Comment: thank you for the response! That's an interesting way to go about it. I'll have a go at getting rid of those abrupt arc transitions and post the result as an answer here if I come up with anything.